# Ansible how to setup a block with multiple when conditionals

Tags: ansible

How best to setup an Ansible block and run the block if a command does not exist or have specific output?

If the command does not exist then stdout would not be available.

```
- name: Check if mybin exists
  stat: 
    path: /usr/sbin/mybin
  register: mybin

- name: Get mybin status
  command: mybin status
  register: status
  when: mybin.stat.exists
  changed_when: false

- name: This node is not yet configured so run this block
  block:
  - name: Install req packages
  ....

  when: 
  - mybin.stat.exists == False 
  - status.stdout.find('successfully setup') == False
```

```
The conditional check 'status.stdout.find('successfully setup') == False' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (status.stdout.find('successfully setup') == False): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'
```

Comment: The error is due to `stdout` being unset, not the usage on a block. => `- "status.stdout is undefined or status.stdout.find('successfully setup') == False"`

Comment: How to check if stdout is unset/set and if set then check the stdout?

Comment: That's in the comment above already.

Answer (score 0):

As the play is written, those two conditions can never both be true at the same time.  You have written the conditions as `and`-ed together.  You need `or`:

```
when: mybin.stat.exists == False or status.stdout.find('successfully setup') == False
```